# CSV Helper Wraps string field ' Name' into double quotes after delimiter?

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I have some troubles with CSV result in my file,
I have written the next configuration in code ( I am working with CSVHelper library)

```
public class ReportModelMap : ClassMap<ReportModel>
{
    public ReportModelMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name).Index(9).Name(" Name");
    }
}
```

The customer requires to add the space between the 'Name' text => " Name".
However, the library wraps the string into ' Name' into double quotes, and for me, it's wrong behavior.
How can I make **--Surname; Name--** instead of **--Surname;" Name"--**?

I can't find any specific configuration to fix it in CsvWriter

My saving logic if it needed

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
   csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ReportModelMap>();
   csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

   csvWriter.WriteRecords(ratingModels);
}
```

Comment: On the contrary, that's the correct behavior. Otherwise clients would just ignore any surrounding whitespace

Comment: What if you change the delimiter to `"; "` ?

Comment: I know that it the rule and it correct behaviour but for the customer, it's necessary to add space for 1 header field. 
I if you change the delimiter to `"; "` it will affect all fields, but I need just 1 field in the heading

Comment: You can use the `ShouldQuote` delegate to determine whether a field needs to be quoted or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Panagiotis Kanavos is correct.  You can use `ShouldQuote` to override the quoting behavior for just that one heading.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var ratingModels = new List<ReportModel>
    {
        new ReportModel { Id = 1, Surname = "Surname", Name = " Name" } 
    };
    
    //using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ReportModelMap>();
        csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
        csvWriter.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => 
        {
            if (!context.HasHeaderBeenWritten && field == " Name") 
            {
                return false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return ConfigurationFunctions.ShouldQuote(field, context); 
            }
        };

        csvWriter.WriteRecords(ratingModels);
    }
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class ReportModelMap : ClassMap<ReportModel>
{
    public ReportModelMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Id).Index(0);
        Map(x => x.Surname).Index(1);
        Map(x => x.Name).Index(2).Name(" Name");
    }
}

public class ReportModel
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```